# unexpected results for regex

Tags: javascript, regex

can someone explain to me why the following regex would return true, it is supposed to test for any uppercase string followed by @ followed by string, why is it that the presence of a digit in the last part is not making it to fail? 
I am running it both from chrome console and javascript code and i'm getting the same result, although testing it on https://regex101.com seems to be working fine.

```
/[A-Z]+@[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]+/.test('AAA@AAA.A1A');
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you failed to use anchors. Anchors helps to do an exact match (*not partial match*).

```
/^[A-Z]+@[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]+$/.test('AAA@AAA.A1A');
```

`^` asserts that we are at the start and `$` asserts that we are at the end of a line.